# How to query callback url for payment status in react?

Tags: reactjs

I want to query a callback URL to be able to render a success message or failure for transactions. So, when payment is initiated on my React app, the user is redirected to a payment gateway to complete the transaction. After completion, the user is redirected back to my app. On my `confirmationPage`, I want to query the URL `params` in order to show the user the payment status message.

```js
const { status, id } = useParams();
const [paymentRef, setPaymentRef] = useState("");
const [paymentStatus, setPaymentStatus] = useState("");

useEffect(() => {
  // If status is 'success', query the payment status
  if (status === "success") {
    Axios.get(
      `${baseurl}/query/transactionid/${id}`,

      {
        headers: {
          "content-type": "application/json",
          "x-access-token": token,
        },
      }
    )

      .then((data) => {
        setPaymentRef(data.data);
        setPaymentStatus("success");
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        setPaymentStatus("failure");
      });
  } else {
    // Set the status to 'failure'
    setPaymentStatus("failure");
  }
}, [id, status]);
```

Here is the instruction from the docs given to me `CONFIRMATION PAGE`
After successful payment, `CoralPay` redirects the user to your Confirmation page (Callback URL provided for payment via web) with two parameters `status=’success’ and id=<transaction_id>`.
If status is **success**, query the ID `using ${baseurl}/query/transactionid/<id>` to retrieve the payment reference and render a success page with success message, e.g. **Your payment was successful** and has been confirmed. Payment reference:`<payment reference>`. If status is not equal to **success**, render failure page.

But from what I have implemented, I get undefined for the `<id>` and the failure message renders even when the transaction is successful. Below is how the URL to query looks, `http://reactappName/paymentstatus/?status=success&id=267062191825950`

Please, I'm confused at this point and any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Dont use useParams. Try new URLSearchParams(useLocation().search).get("status")

Comment: Thanks so much. It really worked as expected